# INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER Xamarin Android

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0

My situation is that I have 2 separate applications, both of which are integrated with Facebook SDK.
Both of them have different authorities that are declared in the AndroidManifest file: (They are using 2 different Facebook apps too.)

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider[facebookAppId01]" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
```

and

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider[facebookAppId02]" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
```

It seems that according to the documentation on Facebook, I've done it right when declaring 2 different ContentProviders for 2 apps. But when I deployed it, this error appeared:

```
1>An error occurred. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
```

If I install the app01 first, I cannot install the app02. Same when I install the app02 first, I cannot install the app01.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Additional information: I downloaded the sample project from Facebook SDK (HelloFacebookSample) and try to deploy it on the same device. Still, the same error occurred. Any solution folks?

Comment: Where should the <provider tag> be on the manifest? Any specific location? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96225/install-failed-conflicting-provider-xamarin-android

this question has been answered here.
I solved this problem by downgrading the SDK to version 4.16.1. Worked perfectly like a charm. Thanks for all the help.

"The version 4.24.0 was released and it's working without problems!" - RafaeldeAndrade

Answer (score 0):

Like I've answered you on the forum (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96225/install-failed-conflicting-provider-xamarin-android), the problem is with the manifest file.

I've found also a bug reported, related to this issue.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56690

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the information. According to the bug report, It is a nuGet package problem. Is there any proper solution for now? This is quite a critical issue for my current projects.